# pattern doesn't match in haskell bytestring

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, bytestring

I am writing a DNA translator using Haskell (`bytestrings` in particular). I have the following code:

```
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Monoid ((<>))
import System.Environment

import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 (ByteString, singleton, splitWith)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as LB
  
-- Extract DNA sequence from fasta file
xtractDNA :: [ByteString] -> Maybe ByteString
xtractDNA dna = Just (LB.concat dna)
--xtractDNA = foldr ((<>) . Just) Nothing 

-- Reverse Complement DNA
compStrand :: Maybe ByteString -> Maybe ByteString
compStrand = foldr ((<>) . compPairs) Nothing
  where
    compPairs nt | nt == (singleton 'A') = Just (singleton 'T')
                 | nt == (singleton 'T') = Just (singleton 'A')
                 | nt == (singleton 'G') = Just (singleton 'C')
                 | nt == (singleton 'C') = Just (singleton 'G')
                 | otherwise = Nothing


main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Welcome to volcano"
  let fname = "/home/trinix/Development/hs_devel/local_data/shbg.fasta"
  fid <- LB.readFile fname
  let dna = LB.concat $ tail (LB.splitWith (==10) fid)
  --putStrLn $ show (LB.length (head dna))
  let dsDna = compStrand (Just dna)
  print dsDna
```

When I execute I get `Nothing` as answer. Part of the input is

> "AATTCTCCATGTGCTTGGATCGTGGGGAAGATGTGATTAAGGTCTAAGGTATGTCTTCCACCAGACAACGGACACAGTCAATTAGAAGCTGGGTAAAGGGGTCTCTCCTGCGGAGCGGGGAGCGCCAAGCCAGGGACAATAATGGCCTGAAGTTCATTCTCCCGGAGATGGGGGTAGAAGCAGGTGCAGGTGCCTTAGAGGGGTCAAAAATAAGAGGAACAGGGTTCACTCTAAGCGGTCTCCCAGGGAAGGCTGCGGGTTGGAGCAAGGGTCCAAGATTCTAAGGGCCAGGACTCAGCTCCAGAAGCTCGATCCCGCCCCACGCGTTCCTGCTCCGGCCAGGGGAGGGGGCTAAGGACCGGCGTCCCCAGTCGGCGCGCCGTCTCACCTTGTAGAAGGCCCCGTTGGAGCCGCGCACCTCGACGGGCAGTCCCGGCTCCACATCCCCCCCAGAGGCCAGGCCGCCCATGGCGCCGCCACCGCCTCCGACTCCCCCGGCGGCGGCTGCAGCAGCAGTCTGAGTGCGGGCCGGGCCAGGCCCCCGGCGTCTCCCCGGAGGAGGAGCCGGAGGGGGAGCCGCGGGGGGCGGGAGCCGGGCCGGCCCCACGGCGGCCCTGCCACAGCCAACGAGCAGGGGGCCGGGGCCGGGCCGCTCCCCGTCCGCCGCCGCCGCCTTGGTCTCCGCC...ACAAGGTCAGAGGCTGGATGTGGACCAGGCCCTGAACAGAAGCCATGAGATCTGGACTCACAGCTGCCCCCAGAGCCCAGGCAATGGCACTGACGCTTCCCATTAAAGCTCCACCTAAGAACCCCC"

My doubt is that my pattern matching guard has some problem. How can I figure that out and solve this issue? Any insights would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `foldr` with as `Foldable` the `Maybe`, not the `ByteString`. It will thus inspect the `Maybe a`. In case it is a `Just` it will call `comPairs` with the *entire* `ByteString` of DNA, otherwise it will return `Nothing`.

Your `comPairs` will return `Nothing` for any `ByteString` that is empty or has two or more bytes, hence it returns `Nothing`.

You can work with a [**`mapM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mapM) to construct a `Maybe [Word8]` and then convert it back to a `ByteString`:

```
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 (ByteString, pack, unpack)

compStrand :: Maybe ByteString -> Maybe ByteString
compStrand = (>>= fmap pack . mapM comPairs . unpack)
    where comPairs 'A' = Just 'T'
          comPairs 'C' = Just 'G'
          comPairs 'G' = Just 'C'
          comPairs 'T' = Just 'A'
          comPairs _ = Nothing
```

Comment: Mind explain what `>>=` does? I understand, `unpack` unpacks `ByteString` as `[Word8]` and `mapM` maps `comPairs` on the list of `[Word8]` and `fmap` applies `pack` on the resulting list of the previous operations.

Comment: @Bussller: for `Maybe`, `(>>=)` has type `Maybe a -> (a -> Maybe b) -> Maybe b`. It thus is a function that will return `Nothing` if the left operand is `Nothing`, as well as when the left one is a `Just x`, and `f x` (with `f` the second operand) returns `Maybe`, it will thus only return a `Just y`, if the left operand is `Just x`, and `f x` produces `Just y`.

Answer (score 0):

`compStrand` is a very strange function. Why does it take a Maybe ByteString instead of an actual ByteString when you only pass it a Just? Why does it do this wacky `foldr ((<>) . compPairs) Nothing` thing which is just a very hard-to-read reimplementation of `(>>= compPairs)`?

`main` is not much clearer: If your input is GATC strings, why are you splitting on the first byte equal to 10? Why doesn't it use this `xtractDNA` function you wrote for it?

Resolving these questions will lead to a simpler function that you can debug more easily on your own. But I will note that it seems like your `compStrand` function operates only on singleton strings, and yet you seem to be passing it a string of unknown size.